# Does US Survey Foot have inches?

Tags: land-survey

From time beyond my remembrance, there are 12 inches in 1 foot. Now later in life, I get introduced to the US Survey Foot and Mile. I see all these calculations for converting between Meters and these other units. And once in a while, I'll see somewhere, someone has taken the foot and divided it by 12 to get inches. My head goes, wait, is that a survey foot or an international foot.

So the question to any surveyor out there is. If the unit is in survey foot or mile, should any of the other conversions(inch, acre, yard) be allowed or should you convert to a known standard first?

For example, I know that an acre is 66 chains by 1 chain or 43560 square feet. But just because I have 43560 square survey feet doesn't mean I have an acre. Yes, I realize the difference is so small. But one thing that happens a lot with software is conversions back and forth, I would call it roundtripping. Errors have a way of creeping in.